# Else If Statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm running the following in R:

```
if (mito$count > 1) {
mito$Polymorphism  <- "SNP"
} else if ((mito$count == 1) & (mito$A_GT == mito$ref | mito$C_GT == mito$ref | mito$G_GT == mito$ref | mito$T_GT == mito$ref)) {
mito$Polymorphism  <- "No"
} else {
    mito$Polymorphism <- ""
}
```

And its giving me the usual error that everyone seems to get:

```
1: In if (mito$count > 1) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if ((mito$count == 1) & (mito$A_GT == mito$ref | mito$C_GT ==  :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I assume this has to do with single value vs a vector (the former, I want to do).  Is there something I need to specify the data frame as beforehand?

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `ifelse()`?

Comment: Now I feel stupid - that worked: `mito$Polymorphism  <- ifelse(mito$count > 1, 'SNP', ifelse(((mito$count == 1) & (mito$A_GT == mito$ref | mito$C_GT == mito$ref | mito$G_GT == mito$ref | mito$T_GT == mito$ref)), 'NO', ''))`

Comment: Write up the answer yourself and after the waiting period, accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifelse()` worked in this situation:

```
mito$Polymorphism <- ifelse(mito$count > 1, 
                            'SNP', 
                            ifelse(((mito$count == 1) & 
                                    (mito$A_GT == mito$ref |
                                     mito$C_GT == mito$ref |
                                     mito$G_GT == mito$ref |
                                     mito$T_GT == mito$ref)),
                                   'NO',
                                   ''))
```